# Read Excel Sheet Data into DataTable or Dataset

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel, dataset

I tried to import from Excel to a dataset and an error message occurred.

I'm studying this site http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_oledb.htm

```
Imports System.Data

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim DtSet As DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim Loc As String = Application.StartupPath() + "\Param\exceldata.xlsx"
            Dim strCOleCon As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" + Loc.Trim + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

            MyConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strCOleCon)
            MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
            DtSet = New DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: _error message occurs_, care to share that error message?

Answer (score 0):

U can use third party EPPLUS which is freeware.Which can import excel file into data set and it also has many functionallities to manipulate the excel file

Answer (score 0):

First off I believe your connection is incorrect, you have an xlsx file but the connection is set for xls.

BTW Not sure if this is a forms or asp project but sure looks like a forms project for windows thinking about your first tag indicating asp.net.

Excel can be tricky in regards to how the connection string is setup, do you want to just read, does the first row in the sheet have column names or data, is there mixed data in a column etc.

Here is a snippet I have used to make things easier with connection but be forewarned it's not fool-proof in that you need to set HDR and IMEX correctly in the connection,

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module ExcelOleDbConnections
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a connection string on read data from an excel file
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="FileName"></param>
    ''' <param name="Header">Yes if first row is column-names, No if first row is data</param>
    ''' <param name="IMEX"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' See following page for clarification on extended properties
    ''' including IMEX. Ignore C# code.
    ''' http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37055/Working-with-MS-Excel-xls-xlsx-Using-MDAC-and-Oled
    ''' </remarks>
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Public Function ExcelConnectionString(
        ByVal FileName As String,
        Optional ByVal Header As String = "No",
        Optional ByVal IMEX As Integer = 1) As String

        Dim Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
        If IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToUpper = ".XLS" Then
            Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
            Builder.Add("Extended Properties", String.Format("Excel 8.0;IMEX={0};HDR={1};", IMEX, Header))
        Else
            Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
            Builder.Add("Extended Properties", String.Format("Excel 12.0;IMEX={0};HDR={1};", IMEX, Header))
        End If

        Builder.DataSource = FileName

        Return Builder.ToString

    End Function
End Module
```

Sample reading a sheet where the first row is data. Note I am using optional parameters so the last two use default values

```
Dim dt As New DataTable

' sheet has data in first row
Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = ExcelConnectionString(Loc)}
    Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1$]"}
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
End Using
```

This example we assume the first row are field/column names

```
Dim dt As New DataTable

' sheet has column names for first row
Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = ExcelConnectionString(Loc, "Yes", 0)}
    Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1$]"}
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
End Using
```

Populate the DataGridView

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
Else
    '
    ' recover e.g. tell user there are no records in this sheet
    '
End If
```

Example all together

```
Try
    Dim Loc As String = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Param\exceldata.xlsx")
    If IO.File.Exists(Loc) Then
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        ' sheet has column names for first row
        Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = ExcelConnectionString(Loc, "Yes", 0)}
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1$]"}
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        End Using


        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Else
            '
            ' recover e.g. tell user there are no records in this sheet
            '
        End If
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("TODO")
End Try
```

See my windows forms examples (yes I see asp.net in your tags)
[Excel and OleDb basics to advance operations](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Excel-and-OleDb-basics-to-95adc5a1)